# Sklearn parallel processing not working in docker container

Tags: docker, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

I'm building and training some RandomForestClassifier models in sklearn. I recently found out about the n_jobs variable to use parallel processing for training and predicting.  However, it seems to have the opposite effect that I'm looking for.

When n_jobs is unassigned (defaults to 1) the training/predicting will entirely use 1 core. I can see 100% CPU usage when running "top".  However, when I bump it to 4, or -1 (number of cores, which is 4) the CPU usage drops to 25%.

Has anyone else run into this before and/or know of a solution?

Comment: Can you see 4 python processes running or not ? I use windows and I can see this from the task manager. When I set 1 I see only one python process and when I set -1 I see 8 python processes as I have 8 cores. The percentage depends on other facts but the point is to see the parallel running

Comment: Nope.  I just tried it w/ n_jobs = 4.  Only 1 python process running at between 28 and 40% of the CPU.

Comment: can you set n_jobs = -1 and tell me what you see? Also, do you use windows?

Comment: I just tried with n_jobs = -1, and it is the same thing, 1 process at 25-40% of the CPU.  I am not on Windows, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: can you follow the 2nd example that I posted as answer? Create a class, indide add your code and finally call it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, with n_jobs=1 it uses 100% of the cpu of one of the cores. Each process is run in a different core. In windows with 4 cores I can clearly see the cpu usage:(100%,~5%, ~5%, ~5%) when I run n_jobs = 1 and (100%, 100%, 100%, 100%) when running with n_jobs = -1.Also, the laptop freezes in the last case. Each process takes the 100% usage of a given core, but if you have n_jobs = 1 only one core is used.

You can also try to add `if__name__==="__main__":` and `n_jobs =-1`

Example 1:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clf = RandomForestClassifier( n_jobs = -1 )
    #more code
```

or
Example 2:

```
Class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        clf = RandomForestClassifier( n_jobs = -1 )
        ###code here    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a misunderstanding on my part.  Apparently my dataset is small enough that the "fit" time is actually pretty negligable (60,000 records or so).  However, I was doing manual cross-validation and would iterate through those records and ask for a prediction on the unseen test set.  This would take several minutes, and I was hoping parallelizing would shave down that time.  However, I think my model is small enough that the overhead of spawning new processes was significantly higher than the speed gained through parallelization.

Basically I generated a sufficiently large (2 million row) random dataset and called "fit" and I did see my CPU usage increase as expected.

Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for those that tried to help!